# I would like to write a dictionary of DataFrames to a single csv file with multiple levels of headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a series of data that looks something like this:

```
example = {'sample A': pd.DataFrame({'Head1':data,'Head2':data}), 'sample B': pd.DataFrame({'Head1':data,'Head2':data})...}
```

I would like to save it into a single csv file with the sample names as headers and the Head1 and Head2 as sub headers.

so far I am just outputting each dataframe into its own csv file using

```py
for sample in example
    example[sample].to_csv(sample+"data.csv",index=False)
```

The csv file should look like the following:

```
Sample A,,      Sample B,,/n     
Head1,   Head2, Head1,   Head2,/n
Data,    Data,  Data,    Data,/n
```

note: there will always be the same number of sub headers for every sample

so far I have thought about concatenating the dataframes into one, writing that to a csv, then adding the new header afterwards, but it seems that there should be a better way.

Comment: Why a single CSV? Have you thought about how you're going to read that file back?

Comment: Also, I just realized that concatenating and then writing a new header afterwards is a bad idea because the sample names could get mixed up and set to the wrong data

Comment: @DroidX86 
the combined csv file will be human read

EDIT: also, I still have the dictionary of dataframes saved in memory. so I can just do anything I need to using that, and then re-save the csv file.

Comment: The csv you want probably looks more like:
```, Sample A, , Sample B, /n     
, Head1, Head2, Head1, Head2/n
Data, Data, Data, Data/n``` 
Otherwise it's not a csv

Answer (score 0):

**1- Create your dummy `DataFrame`:**

```py
import pandas as pd

example = {'sample A': pd.DataFrame({'Head1': [1.0],'Head2': [1.0]}), 'sample B': pd.DataFrame({'Head1': [1.0],'Head2': [1.0]})}
```

**2- Iterate over your `dict`:**

```py
for key, value in example.items():
    value.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[key], value.columns]) # Create the multilayer index
    df = pd.concat([df, value], axis=1, sort=False) # Add DataFrames on the right
```

**3- IMG result:**

[image]

**4- Manipulate the first line of header for a proper csv:**

```py
import csv 

df.to_csv("my_temp_csv.csv")

with open('my_temp_csv.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('my_final_csv.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = reader.next()
    new_header = []
    for element in header:
        if element not in new_header:
            new_header.append(element)
        else:
            new_header.append("")

    w = csv.writer(outfile)
    w.writerow(new_header)

    for row in reader:
        w.writerow(row)
```

**5- Enjoy the csv** (LibreOffice screenshot):

[image]

Comment: I saved your answer to a csv and got this as a result:
```sample A sample A   sample B sample B
Head1   Head2   Head1   Head2
0   1   1   1   1```

Comment: `df.to_csv("my_csv.csv")` gives me ```,sample A,sample A,sample B,sample B
,Head1,Head2,Head1,Head2
0,1,1,1,1```which is indeed a CSV

Comment: I would prefer to not have the main headers repeated

Comment: CSV can't do that. Either you have empty cells either you have repeated first layer header.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. I would prefer to have empty cells as in ```sample A,,sample B, ,Head1,Head2,Head1,Head2 0,1,1,1,1```